# SharePoint Modern list Hyperlink column formatting

Tags: hyperlink, modern

I have a list I am displaying with the "modern" experience that includes a column of the Hyperlink type that links to a status report. The **description** of the Hyperlink is the date that the status report was last updated (manually entered). Can I do conditional formatting on this column based on the Hyperlink description? I would like to convert the description string into a Date and compare it to the current date and format the text red if it is more than 2 weeks old.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Comparison and date operations are only possible if the field is a date object (i.e your column type has to be date). In your case, ideally you would need to add the millisecond equivalent of 2 weeks onto the "@now" reference. Nonetheless, I found a workaround that you might be able to rely on.

You will essentially be comparing the date string you have now against a date string that is 2 weeks in the future. As such, you need to manually update the date that is two weeks into the future. Here is a quick JSON reference that I came up with. I haven't tested its validity but it should provide the basis of a good start.

`{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if @currentField == ' enter date that is two weeks in the future' , '#ff0000', '')"
  }
}`